# Google Chrome initial links typed into address bar lost into the ether?

Tags: google-chrome

When I first open chrome, the first couple of links I type into the address bar completely disappear after pressing enter and the pages aren't loaded.

Running Ubuntu 10.10, is there any known fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome just hasn't finished loading. Another thing is that you might be running a older version - you should be updating every few weeks.

You can also report this as [a bug here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry) at the Chromium project (The open source version of Google Chrome).